# C++ Condition to check for lower number with a treshold

Tags: c++

There surely has to be a better way to do this in C++ that this ?

```
    if ( width_value < tipWidth )
    {
        if (tipWidth < threshold)
        {
            return threshold;
        }
        return tipWidth;
    }
    return width_value ;
```

Comment: I think you'll find the code review site is more useful for questions of this nature

Comment: Unclear what you are asking for.

Comment: what is "better" ? why do you think it could/should be improved?

Comment: Oh .. I dint know there was a code review site. That's helpful info . thank you
 Also to clarify, I was looking for a simpler, readable way of writing the same code without these many lines. Looks like std::max just does that for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    return std::max(width_value, std::max(tipWidth, threshold))
```

Or since C++11:

```
    return std::max({width_value, tipWidth, threshold})
```

That's assuming you `#include <algorithm>` and the type of `width_value`, `tipWidth`, `threshold` is the same. If not the same, you have to specify it explicitly, e.g. `std::max<int>(...)`

Comment: C++ is getting more elegant with each new standard